# Listviewbuilder implementation inside Column won't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a scrollable list on my home screen. I tried to implement my Listviewbuilder called Cardslist() into the home screen, but I always get this exception thrown: **RenderFlex children have non-zero flex, incoming height constraints are unbounded.** Heres the code for the home screen:

```
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/cards_list.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/real_new_finished_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/custom_Buttons.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Screens/new_card_screen1.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Screens/settings.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/card_data.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/cards_list.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'home_screen';
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String individualsName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
              20,
              40,
              20,
              0,
            ),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: kTextFieldInputDecoration,
              onChanged: (value) {
                individualsName = value;
                // TODO: Der Input muss das Individum in der Liste
                // TODO: erkennen und anzeigen
              },
            ),
          ),
          //TODO HIER
          Expanded(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CardsList(),
            ],
          )),

          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: MainButton(
                  functionality: 'New',
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, NewCard.id);
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                SideButton(
                    functionality: 'Settings',
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, Settings.id);
                    }),
                SideButton(
                    functionality: 'Calendar',
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, Settings.id);
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the code for Cardslist():

```
class CardsList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CardData>(builder: (context, cardData, child) {
      return ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final card = cardData.cards[index];
            return FinalCardCreation(
              finalname: card.cname,
              finalbirthday: card.cbirthday,
            );
          });
    });
  }
}
```

The code for the created card FinalCardCreation():

```
class CardFinish extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CardFinishState createState() => CardFinishState();
}

class CardFinishState extends State<CardFinish> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height:
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5, //<-- set height of the card
      child: FinalCardCreation(),
    );
  }
}

class FinalCardCreation extends StatelessWidget {
  String finalname;
  String finalbirthday;

  FinalCardCreation({
    Key key,
    @required this.finalname,
    @required this.finalbirthday,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Color(0xFFef9a9a),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
      elevation: 8,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22)),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Expanded(
            child: FinalCardContent(
              name: finalname,
              birthday: finalbirthday,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FinalCardContent extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
  String birthday;
  FinalCardContent({Key key, @required this.name, @required this.birthday})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              '$name',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              '$birthday',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to wrap my Cardslist() multiple ways but I always got this exception. Thank you for your time and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Column` is a widget that can grow infinitely in height. It does not impose any height constraints to its children. `Expanded` are a smart way to include `ListView`s in `Column` since they fit all the possible space of the `Column` *on screen*, but impose a constraint to their children.

You can either remove the `Column` wrapping your `CardList` or, if you really need that `Column` for other stuff later, try wrapping `CardList` in another `Expanded`.

Comment: I don't need the Column actually. But I got this exception thrown: It says that the relevant error-causing widget was the widget that gets created inside the list which is the FInalCardCreation(it said the error caused the Column in FinalCardCreation).  Thank you for your answer.